# Recomended size for seeker thumb image?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, seekbar, nine-patch

I have a 144x144 png for xxhdpi which looks much to large. I can't seem to find this information anywhere. How could I programatically change the size of the thumb to double the size of the track also?

Comment: your question is very unclear what exactly do you want here

Comment: @G.hakim You can change the thumb image, but what are the recommended resolutions for each density?

Answer (score 0):

> what are the recommended resolutions for each density?

According to [Support different pixel densities](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities):

ldpi    Resources for low-density (ldpi) screens (~120dpi).
mdpi    Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). (This is the baseline density.)
hdpi    Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens (~240dpi).
xhdpi   Resources for extra-high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi).
xxhdpi  Resources for extra-extra-high-density (xxhdpi) screens (~480dpi).
xxxhdpi Resources for extra-extra-extra-high-density (xxxhdpi) uses (~640dpi).